# expo token: Does push token from expo unique per device

Tags: react-native, push-notification, token, expo

I realized the expo notification does not have the Tag abilities as Azure Push Notification does. I wanted to push notification to different devices. Is my assumption correct. The token received from expo is unique per device and the token refreshed only after reinstall the application

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your assumption is correct. The token generated by expo is unique per device-installation. That means that if a user removes the app and re-installs it, a new token will be generated for that device.