# how to send push notification from laravel to expo app

Tags: laravel, react-native, expo

I need someone to tell me how to send notifications from laravel to expo, I searched in the internet I did not understand, and I don't know how to send a notification for push token generated by expo

Answer (score 0):

The easies way I found was to just use the post API provided by expo
I just created a service class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Services;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class ExpoService
{

    public function sendPushNotification($recipients,$title,$body){
        $response = Http::post("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send",[
            "to" => $recipients ,
            "title"=>$title,
            "body"=> $body
        ])->json();
        Log::info($response);
    }


}
```

`$recipients` is an array of tokens

Comment: thank you for your answer, what is the best way to store token for each user and how to mange it

Comment: you can store it in the in the database .every token is unique per device per installation.see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248947/expo-token-does-push-token-from-expo-unique-per-device]

Comment: thank you so much, so $recipients can be one element array like this $recipients = ["ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]"];

Comment: yes it could be an array of single tokens or multiple ones